# Power BI - Get date when sum is 0

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables - `Customer` and `Transaction`. The transaction holds invoices and payments. I need to get the date when the transaction sum is 0 or grater.

So the expected result should be John 02-20-2021. How can I achieve this?

| customerID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Ben |

| customerID | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -150 | 02-13-2021 |
| 1 | 100 | 02-14-2021 |
| 1 | 200 | 02-20-2021 |
| 1 | 10 | 02-23-2021 |

Comment: Can you please explain why the expected result should be ` John 02-20-2021` and why not other dates? If I follow your logic the other dates should qualify as well.

Comment: when the date is 
02-13-2021 the sum is -150. not grater or equal to 0 
02-14-2021 the sum is -50. not grater or equal to 0 
02-20-2021 the sum is 150. it is grater or equal to 0
02-23-2021 the sum is 160. it is grater or equal to 0, but 02-20-21 was true before so i want that date.

So i want the date 02-20-2021. Since this is the first date the sum is equal or grater then 0

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out, by adding some new measures.

First measure to calculate the account balance over dates, returning a value only for positive balance:

```
Account Balance := 
VAR _date = MAX ( Transaction[date] ) 
VAR _balance = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( Transaction[value] ) , 
        Transaction[date] <= _date 
    )
RETURN
IF ( _balance >= 0 , _balance )
```

The second filters the original table based on this measure and returns the earliest date:

```
Break Even Date := 
MINX ( 
    FILTER ( 
        VALUES ( Transaction[date] ), 
        [Account Balance]
    ),
    [date]
)
```

Result:

[image]

Do note that I have not tested this beyond your (simple) example.